# Bhaviveka and Buddhism

Tags: mahayana, texts, comparative-religion, hinduism

The Wikipedia article entitled "[Buddhist influences on Advaita Vedanta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_influences_on_Advaita_Vedanta#Buddhist_criticisms)" states:

> A few Buddhist scholars made the opposite criticism in the medieval
> era toward their Buddhist opponents. In the sixth century AD, for
> example, the Mahayana Buddhist scholar Bhaviveka redefined Vedantic
> concepts to show how they fit into Madhyamaka concepts, and "equate[d]
> the Buddha's Dharma body with Brahman, the ultimate reality of the
> Upanishads.

My question is this an accurate description of the teachings of Bhaviveka? Did he redefine Vedantic concepts to fit a Buddhist view? I want people knowledgeable on this subject to answer.

Comment: Nope, that's a pretty incorrect Indological description of Bhāviveka's standpoint (*it's not the traditional Buddhist standpoint*) held by scholars such as Nakamura, etc. Wikipedia is not a good source, which you must be aware about. Also, the wiki article itself states, that is a position held by 'Buddhist scholars' (these are Indologists primarily, not actual practicing Bauddha bhikṣus). If you want to know Bhāviveka's actual standpoint, it's best to consult his śāstra Mādhyamakahṛdaya alongwith his autocommentary Tarkajvālā.

Comment: There is actually a book, which does provide translations from Tibetan, etc. of the chapters from Mādhyamakahṛdaya & Tarkajvālā, regarding Sāṅkhya and Vedānta https://www.hup.harvard.edu/books/9780674088498 Vedāntatattvaviniścaya is the section in Mādhyamakahṛdaya, in which Bhāviveka gives forth his view. And that's pretty different to the nonsensical standpoint held by Nakamura, Gokhale, etc.
 https://archive.org/details/hinduphilosophyinbuddhistperspectivevedantatattvavinisscayaofbhavyamadhyamakahrd_632_f/mode/2up?view=theater

Comment: If you read Bhāviveka's views, he seems to consider Vedāntavāda as a darśana, which consists of what Tathāgata has already taught, but Vedāntins have messed it up, and don't follow it properly. Furthermore, he seems to show that Vedāntavāda is not very different too in some siddhāntic matters, and that it's best for Vedāntavādins to follow Buddha. Despite this, he does strongly disagree with Vedāntavāda, which does accept an ātman, etc. (unlike Bauddhamata which doesn't). Also, somehow it seems, that he doesn't know Vedānta too well, for he doesn't take it exhaustively, covering all aspects

Comment: Bhāviveka considers Vedānta to be a contradictory and *made-up* mix-mashup siddhānta. Also, he does provide refutation of some matas within Vedānta, as well. Much of that is provided in the pdf document I linked, which you can check.

Comment: kk will look into it thanks for doing your research and answering :)

Comment: Also, Bhāviveka has a long discussion in Mādhyamakahṛdaya, where he puts down Veda too, he doesn't consider it authoritative (prāmāṇya) at all.